# How can I add a column/s to wp_posts table?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field, metabox

I am trying to sync WP with another service that offers an API that allows me to hook up their table's Update, Create, Delete to my sites.

So when they create, update, or delete a row on their server, I get details about that update, including the row ID.

The way I am thinking of syncing is by using custom post types, and either add a new separate table with post -> api relation like `post_id:1 = api_id:53`.

Or alter `wp_posts` table by adding a column containing the api_id.

I know I can add metabox which will add that as post_meta but I am not sure how effective will that be and I am pretty sure if I alter `wp_posts`, querying will be a lot faster.

So how can I alter `wp_posts` in the WordPress way? If that's not possible, should I add meta boxes or create an entirely new table  just for the relation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can technically add a post column with SQL but I'd caution against it as backup scripts, exports etc. would likely ignore it.

Instead, I would add the content as a post_meta, either using a Custom  Field or through PHP with the update_post_meta() function.

To fetch a post based on the meta simply use:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'meta_key' => 'api',
        'meta_value' => $api_value,
      );
$posts = get_posts( $args )
```

or, to fetch the value of the API key

```
get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'api', true );
```

Comment: well 99.99% of the time it would be the other way around, i get the api_id, and need to get the post_id for update

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend creating your own table just for this relation. In this way queries can be faster and you won't have to worry about the table structure of WordPress ever changing and ruining your work (and potentially dropping your column and all its data).

One thing is for sure, you will always have a id to match up against.

**EDIT: Could be done this way, but post_meta has some larger advantages.**

Comment: A custom table is probably overkill -- WordPress allows the use of [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: yea that's what i thought mike yea custom fields, meta boxes.. achieve the same goal basically

Comment: Understood, I could see how it would be easier to leverage the WordPress-y post_meta instead of using another tabled, but I think my way could be faster.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to store meta-information about the posts.  WordPress allows you to do this using its [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).  The functions you'll probably find most useful are [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) and [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

Comment: I wont be able to use neither of those function as i wont know the post ID , when an update happened i need to use an external id to find the post id, and then update the post.

Comment: You'll need to know the post ID to tie the API ID to it in the first place. Then you can use @ChristopherRoss's first code snippet to get the post ID from the API ID.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same problem as the OP. What most of these answers here overlook is the fact that the postmeta table is slow to query, because the meta_key and meta_value columns are not indexed. So if you have an enormous amount of posts, and a correspondingly enormous amount of post meta, then it's going to be time-intensive to get the data you need.

The solution is to use the 'import_id' key when importing the data (which is assuming you're using `wp_insert_post`). This will allow you set the post ID to the API ID, manually. Here's the [relevant section](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3381) on the trac.

Comment: the answers do not overlook anything. When you work with wordpress you work under its limitation or better work with another framework. Changing DB schema is equivalent to changing core code, something you just don't do. Meta is used to extend post information in the way the OP needed, not to do "searches" over it

Comment: If you just have to go this way, as other answers suggest, just create your own table.

Comment: Are you saying that keeping the post ID tied to the API ID is changing DB schema? If so, why would they have the method to use 'import_id' in the first place?

Here's my use case: I'm working with a large database that has 500k posts in it. Those posts are ported in from a different DB, where they have their own IDs. When I run an update from DB 1 to DB 2, I have to use a expensive meta query to figure  out which post to update. If I keep the IDs the same, the query is much much faster.

Comment: the downvote was mostly related to your first paragraph and I admit of missing the point of the second. Still it sounds like an inappropriate use of a column which admittedly core should never had had in the first place, if you want to go that direction guid might be more appropriate. Looking at the documentation of the function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ `import_id` is not even a valid parameter to it and the risk that at some point core will use it for something else is on you

Comment: I agree, that's a fair point that `import_id` could be deprecated. I disagree with your assertion that the answers here don't overlook anything. Two out of three of the answers suggest using post_meta which, as I stated in my original answer, is really slow to query against when you've got hundreds of thousands of posts. WordPress VIP won't let you use meta queries in most cases for this exact reason. Not taking that use case into consideration is the definition of overlooking a detail.

Comment: if the meta slows you down it means that you are searching in it, something which it was never designed to do. meta was designed to bring up extended post information, not to do searches. So I totally understand where you coming from, because that is what everybody does, but the core of the problem is the search you are doing on meta in the first place. From DBs that I  saw, saving one meta row per post not going to impact the number of rows by even 10% (being large here) and therefor will not make a true difference on performance.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: Saying that the metas weren't design to be used in searchs, when there is an argument for meta filtering in the WP_Query, is a pretty dumb statement, and an easy way to ignore that, in fact, metas are pretty slow in large queries. Right now though, it is the way Wordpress manages custom metadata for posts. You could extend the wp_posts table, but it is adviced against